# Possible to publish a powerbi report without password?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

Good afternoon,

Our developers create some nice report with PBI but the problem is they use a database X. those database contain only Development data. Once they want to publish it, we must adapt their report to use the database Y which content Production data.

Is there a way for the developers to publish their report updating the database from X to Y , BUT NOT ADDING THE CREDENTIALS ?
By this way, their report will be refreshed through the Gateway which will be setup to use the UID/PWD link to the DB Y (where the user cannot have access)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, **someone** knows the password for database Y after all, right? Why not this one open the report in Power BI Desktop, change the datasource, and publish it? But there are options to redirect the report published by your developers while the datasource is still the development database (database X).

First, they can use [connection specific parameters](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/bi/power-bi-introduction-working-with-parameters-in-power-bi-desktop-part-4/) to define the datasource. Then, after publishing, the one who knows the credentials update the parameter values to redirect the database to the production database and enter the credentials.

Second one doesn't need any changes to the report. Let your developers publish it, and then use [Power BI REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/) to [change the datasource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/updatedatasourcesingroup) and [patch the credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/gateways/updatedatasource). This can be done for example with PowerShell using [Power BI Management CmdLets](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-apis-and-powershell-cmdlets-for-power-bi-administrators/). First, start PowerShell as administrator and install the CmdLets by executing the following script:

```
Install-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt
```

If you don't have admin rights on the computer, or for some other reason do not want to install these for all users, you can install them for the current user only:

```
Install-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt -Scope CurrentUser
```

You didn't mention what database is used. This is important, so in the following example I will assume it is SQL Server. Update the values in the first few lines to point your production database and published report, then execute the script to change the data source:

```
# Fill these ###################################################
$workspaceName = "The name of the workspace where the report is published"
$datasetName = "The name of the report"
$sqlDatabaseServer = "Server name"
$sqlDatabaseName = "Database name"
$username = "powerbiuser@yourcompany.com"
$password = "the password of the power bi user" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
################################################################

Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt

Clear-Host

$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $credential | Out-Null

$workspace = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Name $workspaceName

$dataset = Get-PowerBIDataset -WorkspaceId $workspace.Id -Name $datasetName

$datasource = Get-PowerBIDatasource -WorkspaceId $workspace.Id -DatasetId $dataset.Id

# Construct url
$workspaceId = $workspace.Id
$datasetId = $dataset.Id
$datasourceUrl = "groups/$workspaceId/datasets/$datasetId/datasources"

# Call the REST API to get gateway Id, datasource Id and current connection details
$datasourcesResult = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Method Get -Url $datasourceUrl | ConvertFrom-Json

# Parse the response
$datasource = $datasourcesResult.value[0]
$gatewayId = $datasource.gatewayId
$datasourceId = $datasource.datasourceId
$sqlDatabaseServerCurrent = $datasource.connectionDetails.server
$sqlDatabaseNameCurrent = $datasource.connectionDetails.database

# Construct url for update
$datasourePatchUrl = "groups/$workspaceId/datasets/$datasetId/Default.UpdateDatasources"

# create HTTP request body to update datasource connection details
$postBody = @{
  "updateDetails" = @(
   @{
    "connectionDetails" = @{
      "server" = "$sqlDatabaseServer"
      "database" = "$sqlDatabaseName"
    }
    "datasourceSelector" = @{
      "datasourceType" = "Sql"
      "connectionDetails" = @{
        "server" = "$sqlDatabaseServerCurrent"
        "database" = "$sqlDatabaseNameCurrent"
      }
      "gatewayId" = "$gatewayId"
      "datasourceId" = "$datasourceId"
    }
  })
}

$postBodyJson = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $postBody -Depth 6 -Compress

# Execute POST operation to update datasource connection details
Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Method Post -Url $datasourePatchUrl -Body $postBodyJson

# NOTE: dataset credentials must be reset after updating connection details
```

Now update the values in the beginning of the following script and execute it to patch the credentials for your production database:

```
# Fill these ###################################################
$workspaceName = "The name of the workspace where the report is published"
$reportName = "The name of the report"
$sqlUserName = "user name"
$sqlUserPassword = "password"
$username = "powerbiuser@yourcompany.com"
$password = "the password of the power bi user" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
################################################################

Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt

Clear-Host

$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $credential | Out-Null

$workspace = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Name $workspaceName

$dataset = Get-PowerBIDataset -WorkspaceId $workspace.Id -Name $reportName

$workspaceId = $workspace.Id
$datasetId = $dataset.Id

$datasources = Get-PowerBIDatasource -WorkspaceId $workspaceId -DatasetId $datasetId

foreach($datasource in $datasources) {

  $gatewayId = $datasource.gatewayId
  $datasourceId = $datasource.datasourceId
  $datasourePatchUrl = "gateways/$gatewayId/datasources/$datasourceId"

  Write-Host "Patching credentials for $datasourceId"

  # HTTP request body to patch datasource credentials
  $userNameJson = "{""name"":""username"",""value"":""$sqlUserName""}"
  $passwordJson = "{""name"":""password"",""value"":""$sqlUserPassword""}"

  $patchBody = @{
    "credentialDetails" = @{
      "credentials" = "{""credentialData"":[ $userNameJson, $passwordJson ]}"
      "credentialType" = "Basic"
      "encryptedConnection" =  "NotEncrypted"
      "encryptionAlgorithm" = "None"
      "privacyLevel" = "Organizational"
    }
  }

  # Convert body contents to JSON
  $patchBodyJson = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $patchBody -Depth 6 -Compress

  # Execute PATCH operation to set datasource credentials
  Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Method Patch -Url $datasourePatchUrl -Body $patchBodyJson
}

$datasetRefreshUrl = "groups/$workspaceId/datasets/$datasetId/refreshes"

Write-Host "Refreshing..."

Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Method Post -Url $datasetRefreshUrl
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

We are using Teradata.

The problem is we want to give flexibility to the end-users; we don't want to be , each time they built/update a report, contacted to publish it (we've got more than 1000 reports PBI ^^). 

About the solution I've test, I've tried also to see if it's possible to add parameters in the connection string in ODBC (once the Get DATA is done) and no way ... My idea was to change the parameter on our gateway once the report is publish

Comment: What does "give flexibility to the end-users" means? It is not clear what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Today our user can publish their report (Several people can updated it) targetting PRD db (Y) which , from a security perspective is anymore allowed. 
In the future, instead to be able to create reports collecting data from the PRD db (Y) they MUST use their own DEV database (X_USER1/2/3/...).
The db X_USER1 is a personalised database meaning if several people work on the report , each have their own DEV database.
¨Problem is , if the user want to set an automated refresh using production database, we must change the DB on the report and configure the connection on our gateway using the db.

Comment: a) or developer are able to adapt and publish their report using the database Y where they don't have access. Problem is PBI Desktop need the uid/pwd and prevent to publish. How skip it?
b) we use parameters in the connection string : DATABASE=@MYDB;DSN=TERADATADEV but there are no way to use variable on the ODBC connection string (we can use it on the Power Query but we would like to avoid that because people creating reports are not IT people).
c) We setup a solution based on Azure Devops (CICD) linked to the solution you've mention (script)
d) We take the ownership of all the reports ...

Comment: It looks like you are looking for [deployment pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/deployment-pipelines-overview) and their [dataset rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/deployment-pipelines-get-started#step-4---create-dataset-rules).